# How To Solve Xampp "Error: My Sql Shutdown unexpectedly"?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I have Installed xamppp and Wordpress. when i go into Browser and try to install wordpress, after Creating the Data base and Giving database name and other necessary things it gives an error on xamp Sql . The error always come on same place same time when i reach to step#2.
[Xamp Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXLuo.png)

Also Heres the logs of MYSql from Xampp
.

```
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 11272
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300288
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 170
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-08-03  5:50:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 13620
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=300685
2023-08-03  6:01:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 3 pages from redo log.
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 301011; transaction id 170
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-08-03  6:01:19 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 11036
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=301095
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 82 pages from redo log.
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-08-03  6:02:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-08-03  6:02:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 453455; transaction id 284
2023-08-03  6:02:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-08-03  6:02:50 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-08-03  6:02:50 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 6076
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=466057
2023-08-03  6:03:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 3 pages from redo log.
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 482002; transaction id 372
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-08-03  6:03:28 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 5256
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-08-03  6:07:41 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=550042
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.28 started; log sequence number 550683; transaction id 456
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-08-03  6:07:42 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I have not tried anything yet because i am new To Xamp and wordpress

Comment: Maybe you don't need xamp at all. Check out if Docker containers / docker-compose setups might be an easier alternative for you: https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/